# can i use dc brushless fan as generator

Tags: brushless-dc-motor

I want to make a small generator from a Dc brushless fan  FD129225HB-N DC 12 volt. can I use this directly to led light of 12volt. I am not good at electrical things please help me.[image]

Comment: No, you can't use a brushless motor on its own as a dynamo, only a brushed motor.

Comment: No, and those youtube videos you've seen of perpetual energy are today's equivalent of snake oil.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev, not at all - I honestly thought you were having a go at me for no reason I could see, yours read as blunt. Oh good and no harm done :-) I'll delete these comments, no value and off-topic - please can you delete your too, thanks

Answer (score 2):

**No**, you can't.

A brushless fan is not just a motor, but has the control electronics built-in, so you can power it from 12V DC instead of having to supply the three phases.

This control circuit is not designed to work as a generator and will not put out any voltage.